# Cannot access NSMutableDictionary outside method where values are passed into it

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am trying to set up Index and sections for my uitableview, which I have managed to do.. However now that I am trying to pass my NSDictionary values over to my uitableviewcell my app is crashing when I try to access the NSDictionary outside of the method that I passed the values to it from.

I am thinking that maybe I am not passing the values in correctly or something along the line of that, but I simply cannot figure out why its going this...

Heres my code...

.h

```
@interface VehicleResultViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

//......

    //Indexed tableview stuff
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *arraysByLetter;
    NSMutableArray *sectionLetters;

}


//.....

//Indexed tableview stuff
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSArray *sortedArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableDictionary *arraysByLetter; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *sectionLetters;

//....
```

.m

```
//...
//This is where I try to access the NSDictionary to pass it to my uitableviewcells
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    } 

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; //make sure their are no tickes in the tableview 
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; // no blue selection

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *value = [self.arraysByLetter objectForKey:[[self.arraysByLetter allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = key;
    NSLog(@"%@",arraysByLetter);

    return cell;
}

//This is where I set NSDictionary
//method to sort array and split for use with uitableview Index
- (IBAction)startSortingTheArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayData
{
    //Sort incoming array alphabetically
    sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    //NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);

    // Dictionary will hold our sub-arrays
    arraysByLetter = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    sectionLetters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Iterate over all the values in our sorted array
    for (NSString *value in sortedArray) {

        // Get the first letter and its associated array from the dictionary.
        // If the dictionary does not exist create one and associate it with the letter.
        NSString *firstLetter = [value substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        NSMutableArray *arrayForLetter = [arraysByLetter objectForKey:firstLetter];
        if (arrayForLetter == nil) {
            arrayForLetter = [NSMutableArray array];
            [arraysByLetter setObject:arrayForLetter forKey:firstLetter];
            [sectionLetters addObject:firstLetter]; // This will be used to set index and section titles
        }

        // Add the value to the array for this letter
        [arrayForLetter addObject:value];
    }
    // arraysByLetter will contain the result you expect
    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", arraysByLetter); //This prints what is currently in the NSDictionary

    //Reloads data in table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

.output of checking the Dictionary with NSLog in the last method above

```
Dictionary: {
    H =     (
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda
    );
    M =     (
        Mazda,
        Mazda,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi
    );
    N =     (
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan
    );
    T =     (
        Toyota,
        Toyota,
        Toyota
    );
}
```

I have debugged the two points (where i set the NSdictionary in the method) and (where I access the NSDictionary in cellforrowatindexpath) and it is defiantly set before I even try to use it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

```
//Indexed tableview stuff
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sortedArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *arraysByLetter; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sectionLetters;
```

**REMOVE** IBOutlet from properties declarations. It's only for Interface Builder controls.

Also correct dictonary allocation - `self.arraysByLetter = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`

Comment: cheers, this made my NSLog print out inside cellforrowatindexpath method.. So that means I can now access my NSDictionary outside of the method... however the way im trying to access it is still crashing..  NSString *value = [self.arraysByLetter objectForKey:[[self.arraysByLetter allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; dosnt work.. need to figure that one out :P

Comment: this is the error im getting
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

Answer (score 2):

The `NSMutableDictionary` that is allocated is `autoreleased`, therefore when it is called in the other method the `NSAutoreleasePool` has been drained, and the `NSMutableDictionary` has been `released`. If you want to retain the object using the property you have to do it like this:

```
self.arraysByLetter = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

`self` will set the dictionary using the setter which is declared as `retain`, so it will be available when you try to use it later on.

As a note any method that **does not** start with new or alloc or contains copy must return an `autoreleased` object, which is your case.

Comment: cheers, thank you for clarifying that for me.. I lost all concept of this after the xcode update where they updated how retain / release worked..